# Is it possible to customise the search engine buttons in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, search

When searching in gnome-shell, there are two buttons towards the bottom of the screen which can be used to search with Wikipedia and Google.

Is there any way to customise these? If, say, I wanted to replace the Google button with one for DuckDuckGo, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Gnome-Shell search providers are described by XML files in the folder `/usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers`

You will notice two XML files - *google.xml* and *wikipedia.xml*

Lets create a new search provider - copy the *google.xml* file as a template

**11.10**

```
sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers/google.xml /usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers/duckduckgo.xml
```

**12.04**

```
sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/open-search-providers/google.xml /usr/share/gnome-shell/open-search-providers/duckduckgo.xml
```

Now lets open the file and change some details to search with duckduckgo:

**11.10**

```
sudo nano /usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers/duckduckgo.xml
```

**12.04**

```
sudo nano /usr/share/gnome-shell/open-search-providers/duckduckgo.xml
```

Change the following XML tags:

```
<ShortName>DuckDuckGo</ShortName>
<Description>DuckDuckGo Search</Description>
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://www.duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}"/>
```

The only difficult part is finding out how a search engine searches - in duckduckgo I searched for something - you see in the title bar how the search provider adds its search terms

[image]

*final result*

[image]

In order to see the changes, you need to restart GNOME Shell by pressing Alt+F2, typing "r" and pressing enter.

---

Linked Questions:

1. [Is it possible to re-arrange the search providers on the GNOME Shell Activities Overview display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89842/is-it-possible-to-re-arrange-the-search-providers-on-the-gnome-shell-activities/89848#89848)

Comment: Oh, wow! Thanks! 
The files are just OpenSearch plugins. I didn't realise it would be this easy.

The big string of what looks like gobbledegook is in fact a copy of Google's favicon. I don't think GNOME uses it, but I replaced it with DDG's favicon just to be safe.

Comment: This no longer seems to work with new shell. Even changing the folder to open-searchproviders. Alternatively you can use the https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/549/web-search-dialog/ not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone's interested in removing all search engines from the overlay screen, user asermax has published the Disable Search extension at the [GNOME Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) website. Check it out: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/203/disable-search/

It must be noted that this extension also removes the search bar at the top right corner of the overlay screen.