# Is it possible to remove or replace Google search in GNOME Shell's dash?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, search, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to customise the search engine buttons in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67660/is-it-possible-to-customise-the-search-engine-buttons-in-gnome-shell)

I am have made a couple of posts about GNOME 3.2. And I know its not technically finished yet. Not necessarily beta anymore, but still a huge list of things missing and big gap left for built in customizablity (no I do not consider the Gnome Tweak tool as "built in". That being said, I LOVE IT SO FAR! :-D

I really like the idea of being able to do a web search on (" insert favorite search engine name ", mine just so happens to be DuckDuckGo.com ) straight from the desktop. But Google and Wikipedia are the only ones there and I have heard of no extentions or changeable settings/conf files for this. Is it possible to remove and/or add new search engines to these options? (Highlighted below)

[image: Image of my Gnome 3.2 dash showing a search and highlighting the Search engine options]

Obviously doing it the manual way requires knowing what the search URL would be so that your search term would be automatically inserted and then open the browser, but with DuckDuckGo they have great pages about what URL to use where for these kinds of things. So no big deal there.

What do you guys think? Up to the challenge? ;-)