# Is it possible to re-arrange the search providers on the GNOME Shell Activities Overview display?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, search

I have added additional search providers (e.g., AskUbuntu, Wolfram, YouTube) in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers` directory.  These work great.  However, the order in which they appear on the **Activities Overview** is not logical.

Is it possible to change the order in which search providers are displayed?

Bonus:  How do I make one the default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### 11.10

There is a key that is referred to in the gnome-shell search code that allows you to specify which search providers should *not* be displayed...

By changing the logic you can change that to be a search order list - for example

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell disabled-open-search-providers "['duckduckgo.xml', 'google.xml', 'wikipedia.xml']"
```

[image]

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell disabled-open-search-providers "['wikipedia.xml', 'duckduckgo.xml', 'google.xml']"
```

[image]

**how to**

First make a backup copy of the search script:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/search.js /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/search.js.backup
```

Now edit the search script:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/search.js
```

Look for the function containing the following code (it probably starts on line 325):

```
 _refresh: function() {
        this._providers = []; 
        let names = global.settings.get_strv(DISABLED_OPEN_SEARCH_PROVIDERS_KEY);
        let file = Gio.file_new_for_path(global.datadir + '/search_providers');
        FileUtils.listDirAsync(file, Lang.bind(this, function(files) {
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                let enabled = true; 
                let name = files[i].get_name();
                for (let k = 0; k < names.length; k++)
                    if (names[k] == name)
                        enabled = false;
                if (enabled)
                    this._addProvider(name);
            }           
        }));    
    }
```

Change this function to be:

```
_refresh: function() {
        this._providers = [];
        let names = global.settings.get_strv(DISABLED_OPEN_SEARCH_PROVIDERS_KEY);
        let file = Gio.file_new_for_path(global.datadir + '/search_providers');
        FileUtils.listDirAsync(file, Lang.bind(this, function(files) {
            for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                for (let k = 0; k < files.length; k++) 
                    if (names[i] == files[k].get_name())
                        this._addProvider(names[i])
            }               
        }));    
    }
```

Press Alt+F2, type 'r' and press enter. This should restart Gnome-shell). Alternatively, logout and login.

<sub>[credit](http://bin.baobaojia.org/2011/11/25/customize-the-order-of-open-search-providers-in-gnome-shell/)</sub>

---

Linked Questions:

1. [Is it possible to customise the search engine buttons in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67660/is-it-possible-to-customise-the-search-engine-buttons-in-gnome-shell/72548#72548)
2. [Is it possible to remove or replace Google search in GNOME Shell's dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73039/is-it-possible-to-remove-or-replace-google-search-in-gnome-shells-dash)

Answer (score 2):

To preserve the meaning of the gsettings variable, another possibility would be to modify `search.js` to order search providers files by name:

```
    FileUtils.listDirAsync(file, Lang.bind(this, function(files) {
        files.sort (function (first, second) {
            return first.get_name () <= second.get_name ()? -1: 1
        });
```

Then you would rename the files in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers` like

```
01_google.xml
02_wikipedia.xml
...
```

Carlo.

Answer (score 2):

I found that it arranges them in time order. The search provider which was added latest is first. So if you want to bring Google first just move it somewhere, refresh (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and R), recopy it to the folder and refresh again.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method: Gnome Shell seems to favour the search provider tied to the most recently edited `.xml` file; to create a custom arrangement, it will be enough to open the files, save them, and restart the shell. If your desired order is, for example: Google, Wikipedia, DuckDuckGo - then DuckDuckGo should be the one you save first, followed by Wikipedia and then Google.