# How to create an Ask Ubuntu search button in gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome

On the overview in gnome-shell, there are two search buttons for Google and Wikipedia. Is it possible to create a similar button for Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I have found [fossfreedom's answer to create a DuckDuckGo search button in gnome-shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67660/is-it-possible-to-customise-the-search-engine-buttons-in-gnome-shell/72548#72548) to be useful and I have used it as a base to answer this question.*

To create a new search provider, copy the *google.xml* file as a template.

**11.10**

```
sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers/google.xml /usr/share/gnome-shell/search_providers/askubuntu.xml
```

**12.04**

```
sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/open-search-providers/google.xml /usr/share/gnome-shell/open-search-providers/askubuntu.xml
```

Change the following XML tags in the *askubuntu.xml* file:

```
<ShortName>Ask Ubuntu</ShortName>
<Description>Ask Ubuntu Search</Description>
<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://askubuntu.com/?q={searchTerms}"/>
```

If you have done everything right, you should be seeing the Ask Ubuntu search button in the overview.

[image]

Comment: `<Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="http://askubuntu.com/search?q={searchTerms}"/>` (Use this url string instead, to make use of the search function! - Curious, no one mentioned it!!)

Comment: @v2r Very good point indeed. Changed the URL as you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome jokerdino!