# Enable web Search in gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, search

Unfortunately i disable gnome-shell web search option with the following command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell disabled-open-search-providers "['google.xml', 'wikipedia.xml']"
```

How to re-enable it?

Also how can i change the default search. Default gnome-shell search in wikipedia. I need to search in google by default.

thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't work to me!!
I tried [code] gsettings set org.gnome.shell disabled-open-search-providers "[]" [code]
but nothing!
They're still out!
I did the same wrong of the first asker, but i'm not able to solve it!
thanks
federico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem you should simply open dconf-editor (maybe you should install it first), then go to org>gnome>shell and void the disabled-open-search-providers' string.

Otherwise, you can simply do in a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell disabled-open-search-providers "[]"
```

For the second problem, there's already an answer (follow the links at the end of the answer to that question): [Is it possible to customise the search engine buttons in GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/a/72548/29595)

Comment: Alternatively, you could just click the "Set to Default" button on the bottom right of the dconf-editor's window.